# command prompt commands (MOVE)

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, move, access-denied

i am using **windows 7 32 bit ultimate**, i want to know if anyone can use **cmd or command prompt** (move command) and fix this problem :

### i have folder (mypro) on drive (C) and i also have same folder on (D) drive. now when i use cmd like the following it says "access denied"

c:> move mypro d:\

access denied

c:>

---

c:> move/y mypro d:\

access denied

### c:>

c:> move/-y mypro d:\

access denied

c:>

---

also i i run with administration rights but its not working again

Comment: What are you trying to do? Move all the files from the C folder to the D folder? Or overwrite the D folder?

Answer (score 0):

In case there are **no subfolders** in your `c:\mypro\` -folder, try this:

`move /y mypro\* d:\mypro\`

In case you've got subfolders the solution seems to require a BAT-file. 
If you need that, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using Xcopy and then remove the directory on C,

I think you have a directory "Mypro" on C partition, and you have the same folder "Mypro" on partition D:

You can try this solution:

**First**: copy entire directory within sub-directory using Xcopy like this

**C:>xcopy /s /e /y MyPro d:\MyPro**

/s: Copies directories and subdirectories except for empty ones.

/e: Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.

/y: Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
     existing destination file.

**Second**: remove the entire directory "MyPro" on partition C while you move all files/folders

**C:>rmdir /s mypro**

/s: Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
in addition to the directory itself.

Please let me know if your problem doesn't solve.

```
C:\>xcopy /s /e /y MyPro d:\MyPro
C:\>rmdir /s mypro
```